# setting up a postinst to run SQL file

Tags: debian

what i am attempting to accomplish is to have my postinst file be executed before my Debian package is installed. attempting to start an SQL import to create the database and tables
i have the Following in my preinst in my DEBIAN folder

```
#!/bin/bash

  DB_USER="#"
  DB_PASSWORD="#"
  DB_NAME="#"
  MAINDB="#"

  mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE ${MAINDB} /*\!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;"
  mysql -h localhost -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME < sqlfile.sql
```

but it is not finding the sqlfile.sql to import, know matter where i place the sql file it never see's it, where do i put this file . ? or is there a better way to accomplish this .

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

```
mysql ... < sqlfile.sql
```

You should use an absolute path to `sqlfile.sql`.  This is currently a relative path.  Where you do think the working directory of `postinst` is?  I think it runs in `/`, but I've never relied on that.

Second, where did `sqlfile.sql` come from?  `preinst` is called before your package is unpacked [1].  If `sqlfile.sql` is in your package, then it hasn't been unpacked into the filesystem yet.  In that case, move your logic to `postinst`.  You might need to make sure the line of code comes before whatever is in `postinst` that needs this to run so early.

If `sqlfile.sql` is in a dependency package, be sure to use `Pre-Depends:` on that package.  That's the only way to ensure `sqlfile.sql` has been deployed before `preinst` is called (though the Pre-Depends: package may only be in an "Unpacked" or "Half-Configured" state.

If `sqlfile.sql` is a temporary file, then install it to `/usr/lib/mypkg/sqlfile.sql` and use it from there in your `postinst`:

```
mysql ... < /usr/lib/mypkg/sqlfile.sql
```

---

Finally, your maintainer scripts may be called several times during installation.  This isn't your problem, but it's good to only trigger specific code during specific invocations.    Here's some template code you can use.  Put any code you want to run in the appropriate case statements:

```
#!/bin/sh
# preinst template
set -e

case "$1" in
    install|upgrade)
    ;;

    abort-upgrade)
    ;;

    *)
        echo "preinst called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
#DEBHELPER#
exit 0
```

```
#!/bin/sh
# postinst
set -e

case "$1" in
    configure)
    ;;

    abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
    ;;

    *)
        echo "postinst called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
#DEBHELPER#
exit 0
```

[1] https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html#summary-of-ways-maintainer-scripts-are-called